# QGIS coloring NULL values

Tags: qgis, color, null, categorized-renderer

I am using QGIS Version 2.14.3.
I have a map with polygons and a lot of different attributes. Some polygons have NULL values in some columns. 
I've tried to color the polygons with properties->style->graduated. But in some columns half of the values are NULL and now they don't have any colour.

I know that i could color the NULL values when I chose "categorized" coloring, but I have way to many different entries to do that, because QGIS chooses a colour for every different entry.

I need to have intervals for coloring. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Do you store numbers of what else?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use [rule based styling](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html?highlight=classification#hard-fa-rule-based-classification).

Basically, you will create a few rules. One will be `"field_name" IS NULL`, and the others will be `"field_name" <= 20 AND "field_name" >= 11`.