# Representing NULL data for a numeric field in ArcGIS (symbology)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, null

I have a tank age data set which I would like to present on ArcGIS.

I would like to represent the different tanks using their tank age. I would like the symbol colour to be dependent on the tank age (think red, green, yellow).

The problem is, there are some tanks which I don't have the tank age for.

How can I represent the tanks that don't have tank age?

Should I:

- Put in the tank age as 'N' to give it a character input
- I can't put a dummy number such as -9999 since I have other graphical representations that rely on that age field and -9999 would skew the charts.

Edit:
- I could create a different column for Null_values and ask the symbology to draw off that. I'm unsure if we can represent one symbology from different fields.
- Grey of blank would be a great visual but I'm not sure how to map off the NULL data.

[image: Symbology]

[image: Raw Data]

[image: Symbol definition]

Comment: Is your question about how to symbolise it, or how to record it in your data?

Comment: How are you trying to symbolize them? Is tank age a numeric, date or character field? Perhaps you can split the layer into two layers by definition query (tank_age is not NULL and tank_age is NULL) give one an age symbology and the other a single symbol.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for  your reply. Always good to get your input. I guess that is one way to do it, although not as efficient, since I will need an extra field, and any reports I do afterwards might have that 'gap'. The link below sums up what I'd like to do. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241284/qgis-coloring-null-values

Comment: I like the absence of color to represent the absence of data: white, black, or a gray color.

Comment: Nice comment Dan, the thing is behind the white, black or gray, there needs to be some sort of data to represent it. At the moment there is no data in the field to represent it and I'm wondering what I should do to fix that.

Comment: @DanShek Is your question about how to symbolise it, or how to record it in your data? Please [edit] your question to include this plus any other new information in response to comments

Comment: Also add an example of what your data currently looks like

Comment: Are you using Shapefiles?  I'm guessing as your question seems to indicate that you are unable to record the `NULL`

Comment: Alright, I added some screen shots. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: @DanShek Can you also show how you've defined your symbology?  Why can't you use `NULL` as another symbol option?

Comment: It must be a geodatabase table as shapefiles don't support Null. You don't need an extra field, Null is a value not like any other as it can cause problems later on when you try to summarize.. I would suggest -1 for age that's unspecified; any negative age would do as it's a clearly nonsensical value. Using a *real* but nonsensical value will hopefully insulate you against further problems when summarizing... just be aware that they're there if you want to find the mean of age or similar. When using a classified renderer you can set an exclusion value or manually classify to give -1 a colour.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I've added an extra screenshot of my symbol definition. I'd say the answer is mostly there in relation to my original question. It's just that I am using infographics (widget) when displaying the tank age, so there will be a -1 showing up, and I don't think I can change that display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an exclusion in your symbol classification.  In your Layer Properties > Symbology tab, click *Classify*.  In the *Classification* dialog click Exclusion:

[image]

On the *Query* tab, add an exclusion for your `NULL` values:

```sql
Tank_Age IS NULL
```

[image]

Change to the *Legend* tab and check *Show symbol for excluded data*

[image]

Now your `NULL` values will show as symbolised.  You can symbolise them however you want here.

[image]

[image]